# Change the line after text element in a report

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2009

How i can make a break line in a row after the text element in axapta report?

I tried to set a width of a text element to column width, but the next string elements didnt change the line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways:

1. Have more than one body section
2. Force the field in location setting property Top: 1 char, you may have set Left as well

Comment: After set a top and left in the nextcolumn the row changes, thank you!